# Determine if custom jasmine matcher is chained with `not`

Tags: javascript, jasmine

When writing a custom matcher you have to add a message in case the test fails. But in my case the message is different if the matcher is chained with `not`

```
expect(el).toHaveClass('bar-foo');
```

vs

```
expect(el).not.toHaveClass('bar-foo');
```

And a simple matcher which checks if the class exists or not:

```
var customMatchers = {
    toHaveClass: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return function (elm, cls) {
            return {
                pass: elm.classList.contains(cls),
                message: `Class "${cls}" is not present`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the test fails the matcher will return **Class "bar-foo" does not exist**

Which is fine, but if the matcher is called with `not` this message is incorrect. How can I determine inside the matcher if it was chained with `not?

Comment: The documentation seems to describe this scenario: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html

Comment: I've red it again, and now I understand, it's subtle! : ) Thnx